# nginx failed (13: Permission denied) uwsgi (502 bad gateway)

Tags: centos, nginx, permissions, uwsgi

I am having trouble running my application on a new DigitalOcean droplet. The machine runs CentOS 6.5

My `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
user  nginx www-data;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
(continues)
```

My `myapp_nginx.conf`

```
server {

   server_name 104.xxx.x.xxx;
    listen      8080;
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 30M;

    location / {
        index index.html index.htm;
        root /home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_portal;
        try_files $uri @app;
    }

    location /static {
    alias /home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_portal/app/static;
    }

    location @app {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_portal_uwsgi.sock;
    }
}
```

My `myapp_uwsgi.ini`

```
[uwsgi]
master = true
#user info
uid = webdev
gid = www-data

#application's base folder
base = /home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_portal

#chdir to this folder when starting
#chdir = /home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_portal

#python module to import
app = run_web
module = %(app)

home = /home/webdev/mydevelopment/venvs/ecodev_do
pythonpath = %(base)

#socket file's location
socket = /home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_portal/%n.sock

#permissions for the socket file
chmod-socket    = 666

#the variable that holds a flask application inside the module imported at line #6
#uwsgi varible only, does not relate to your flask application
callable = app

#location of log files
logto = /home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_portal/logs/%n.log
```

The error messages printed in the nginx `error.log` whenever I make a web request to `104.xxx.x.xxx:8080`

```
2014/11/19 23:14:47 [crit] 28090#0: *1 stat() "/home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_portal/favicon.ico" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 71.211.xxx.xxx, server: 104.xxx.x.xxx, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "104.xxx.x.xxx:8080"
2014/11/19 23:14:47 [crit] 28090#0: *1 connect() to unix:/home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_portal_uwsgi.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 71.211.xxx.xxx, server: 104.xxx.x.xxx, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_portal_uwsgi.sock:", host: "104.xxx.x.xxx:8080"
```

project folder: `drwxr-xr-x 6 webdev www-data 4.0K Nov 19 23:40 ers_portal`

socket inside that folder: `srw-rw-rw- 1 webdev www-data    0 Nov 19 23:45 ers_portal_uwsgi.sock`

If you have any additional info you need just let me know. Thanks!!

**EDIT**

I changed the permissions as suggested by @Eugene. Now in my `/var/log/nginx/access.log` I see

```
[20/Nov/2014:01:37:58 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 574 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

In `/var/log/nginx/error.log` I see

```
2014/11/20 01:38:27 [crit] 28639#0: *1 connect() to unix:/home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_portal_uwsgi.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 71.21.my.local.ip, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_portal_uwsgi.sock:", host: "104.ser.ver.ip"
```

The favicon.ico rejection (below) that was in `var/log/nginx/access.log` isn't showing up anymore

```
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 574 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Comment: Check the permissions of all containing directories, and also check `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton `audit.log` looks like it is mostly my `sudo` commands  and logins maybe? I'm not sure what to look for. If I `tail -f audit.log` and reload `104.my.ip.add:8080` nothing is logged. I `chmod -R myappfolder` as well. `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart && uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini ` it still gets rejected. `myappfolder/favicon.ico` gets looked at first and `failed (13: Permission denied)`

Comment: Try to set the socket permission to 0666

Comment: The socket permission is set in the `uwsgi.ini` file. This happens each time the uwsgi application is started. Additionally, I have a working configuration of this same code on a different CentOS box and the socket permissions are the same.

Comment: Worth noting this can also happen if you're on a machine with selinux enabled and the directory doesn't have the right selinux type, in which case you'd need to use `chcon`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solved**

I found my typo after many hours of searching. In `/path/to/my/webapp/my_app_nginx.conf` the line that reads

```
location @app {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_portal_uwsgi.sock;
    }
```

should read

```
location @app {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_portal/ers_portal_uwsgi.sock;
    }
```

Also, in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` change `user  nginx www-data;` back to `user nginx;`

Also ensure that there is not a default server block in the "top-level" `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` that conflicts with your app's configuration (in my case `/path/to/my/webapp/my_app_nginx.conf`, which is symlinked to the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` folder).

Lessons learned...

1. Don't get discouraged. The worst (maybe second worst) feeling in the world is not being able to figure something out over an extended period of time. Especially if this is your hobby, it can be easy to feel that you're incompetent and this stuff is too hard and you're not good enough. Stick at it.
2. Be methodical. I was getting change-crazy, especially at the end there. This results in going to bed with no real progress and waking up in the same spot you were. Write it all down, document what you have tried and keep track of previous changes. if `ABABA` is the working config, and `---B-` was the change you were looking for, but you forgot to change `--B--` back to `--A--`, you will repeat and repeat and repeat yourself. See #1
3. Remember sometimes the most important thing to reaching your solution is to get up and walk away.
4. Don't discount the knowledge of your peers (this community). While they may not have the instant answer for your particular problem, remember *All of us isn't as dumb as none of us* (or some silly saying like that). We all have a deep-seated love of scrubbing problems from the planet, one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you don't have proper permissions somewhere on the path to `/home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_portal` - although `ers_portal` seem to have proper 755, some directories don't. Check that all the directories starting from `/` to `ers_portal` have at least 5 for the www-data user, or it's group, or to all.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with line

```
 try_files $uri @app;
```

Just comment it and restart nginx server. It should solve the issue.